# How to update a phone gap-app (iOS)

Tags: ios, cordova

I have a working app, which I created a year ago - because its always difficult to update the app I waited for almost a year (bad idea)

Now that a lot has changed over the last few months I don't know where to start. And the Cordova-Website isn't very precise about that as well

I have xcode 5.1.1 and I guess Cordova 2.9 (I don't know exactly, so maybe you could tell me, how I get Info about my version)

Do I have to update my project from 2.9 to 3.0 to 3.1.0 to ...3.4.0
or is there a way to update it from 2.9.0 to 3.4.0 in one step?

Comment: maybe I should add: the app is working - I haven't published it on iTunes yet. Thats what i meant with "working app"

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to 3.0 it's easy to upgrade to 3.4 using the cli. Simply use the command:
"cordova platform update ios".
See here for getting to 3.0: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_ios_upgrading.md.html#Upgrading%20iOS

You could also simply create a new project with 3.4 and copy your relevant files from /www/ into it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to update to 3.0 right now. On [this manual](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.6.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) it says: I should download & install a git-client. But when I download the 2.1.1 latest release of git [on this site](http://git-scm.com) , the dowload-manager tells me its 2.0.1 intel universal snow leopard - I'm using Mavericks.